# How to insert all rows from one table in the column in () statement in Hive

Tags: hive

I have a table with 100 strings that I would like to add to a `where column in (value, value, etc)` Something like `select cookies from table where field in (select * from table)`

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. `Hive` does have an `IN` clause, so what's the issue here? Or when you say a table with 100 strings, do you mean a table with 100 columns and you need to select all the columns in the sub-query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Hive supports subqueries in `in` clauses, but you can accomplish the same with an inner join:

```
select table1.cookies
from table1 join table2 on table1.field = table2.field
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive does have a support of SUB-QUERIES from version-0.13.
So you can use this version.
Or you can try this query:

```
select * from table1 t1 JOIN (select 100_string_column as col2 from table2 where (whatever your condition is)) t2 ON t1.<matching_column> = t2.col2
```

Hope this helps...!!!